# redirect all url from a root domain to a subdomain, except homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, multisite

I had the following wordpress multisite:

```
mysite.com
city2.mysite.com
city3.mysite.com
```

that became these:

```
mysite.com
city1.mysite.com
city2.mysite.com
city3.mysite.com
```

**mysite.com** should become a single landing page and i want all the urls starting like *mysite.com/myurl* redirecting to *city1.mysite.com/myurl*.

Note that all the websites use the same `.htaccess`.

I tried to implement a lot of examples found on Stackoverflow, but none of them covered this case and my attempts to adapt the code didn't work.

Thank you,

Bru

Answer (score 0):

This is a helpful plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

I have not used in multisite, but I feel it should be fine.